# Convert python script to binary executable

Tags: python

I wrote a number crunching python code. The calculations involved can take hours. Is it possible somehow to compile it to binary?

Thanks

Comment: When you Googled "Compile Python to Binary" what did you find?  Do you have specific questions on the tools you found with that Google search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Shedskin](https://web.archive.org/web/20161208040640/http://code.google.com/p/shedskin/) might be worth a try.

From their front page blurb:

> Shed Skin is an experimental compiler,
> that can translate pure, but
> implicitly statically typed Python
> programs into optimized C++. It can
> generate stand-alone programs or
> extension modules that can be imported
> and used in larger Python programs.
>
> Besides the typing restriction,
> programs cannot freely use the Python
> standard library (although about 20
> common modules, such as random and re,
> are currently supported). Also, not
> all Python features, such as nested
> functions and variable numbers of
> arguments, are supported (see the
> tutorial for details).
>
> For a set of 44 non-trivial test
> programs (at over 10,000 lines in
> total (sloccount)), measurements show
> a typical speedup of 2-40 times over
> Psyco, and 2-220 times over CPython.
> Because Shed Skin is still in an early
> stage of development, however, many
> other programs will not compile
> out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 5):

Not in any useful (for you) way, but moving the calculations into [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) or [Cython](https://cython.org/) will speed them up.

Answer (score 3):

First you can try psyco, that may give you a speed up as much as 10x, but 2x is more typical

If you can post the code up somewhere, perhaps someone can point out how to leverage numpy.

If your task doesn't map well only numpy then cython is a good choice to convert a intensive function or two into C code just by adding a few cdefs.

If you can show us the code (even just the hot spots) we can probably give you better advice.

Perhaps you can modify your algorithm